# How to send a var to router

Tags: node.js, express

Maybe in express, there are some thing changed. But I don't know how to send the session:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use('/', routes);
```

to another .js file router.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

generally seesion we configure in configure section like this

```
var express = require('express')
var parseurl = require('parseurl')
var session = require('express-session')

var app = express()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

in controller level we can access the session like

req.session
we can access seesion

to regenerate the session

```
req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
  // will have a new session here
})
```

destroy seesion

```
req.session.destroy(function(err) {
  // cannot access session here
})
```

store the value in session

```
req.session.key = value;
```

retrieving value from session

```
req.session.key
```

refer the given link 
https://github.com/expressjs/session

we can pass api object to route configuration like this ;

```
var api = require('express'); 
require('../api/routes/authorization.routes.js')(api);
```

in route configuration

```
   module.exports = function (api) {

        api.route('/api/authorization/token')
            .post( authorization.token);


    };
```